# Get item by name or id in QgsReport

Tags: pyqgis, reports

There is a customized report in QGIS, this report has an HTML element. The task is to programmatically change the contents of HTML

```
project = QgsProject.instance()
project.read(report_proj_path)
layoutmanager = project.layoutManager()
layout = layoutmanager.layoutByName('test')
html_frame = layout.itemById('attributes_table')
html_table = html_frame.multiFrame()
table_data = '<table><tr><td><b>Code</b></td><td>[%code%]</td></tr><tr><td>Page number</td><td>[%"page_number"%]</td></tr><tr><td>district</td><td>[%district%]</td></tr></table>'
html_table.setHtml(table_data)
html_table.setContentMode(1)
html_table.loadHtml()
```

Get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'QgsReport' object has no attribute 'itemById'
```

Need to acces to HTML element and change its content.

Python version: 3.9.5
QGIS version: 3.28.3

Comment: What made you think that QgsReport had an `itemById` method?

Comment: Mind the warnings about the API being not stable! You do not actually get a QgsLayout but a QgsReport and that has a [.layout()](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.28/core/QgsAbstractReportSection.html#qgis.core.QgsAbstractReportSection.layout) method you might be able to get the layout from. Alternatively you might have to use [.childSections()](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.28/core/QgsAbstractReportSection.html#qgis.core.QgsAbstractReportSection.childSections) to dive deeper into your report's structure.

Comment: Thanks @bugmenot123!
Helps me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments @bugmenot123

```
project = QgsProject.instance()
project.read(report_proj_path)
layoutmanager = project.layoutManager()
layout = layoutmanager.layoutByName('test')
rep_sections = layout.childSections()
for r_sec in rep_sections:
    if r_sec.body().itemById('attributes_table'):
        html_frame = r_sec.body().itemById('attributes_table')
        html_table = html_frame.multiFrame()
        table_data = create_html_table()
        html_table.setHtml(table_data)
        html_table.setContentMode(1)
        html_table.loadHtml()
```